# How to see the changes for more than one edit in one merged version view in a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs, version-control

When I opened a doc after some months, I saw that others had worked on it. I was offered a button:

[image]

"See new changes"
("See changes since you last viewed this document")

There was a merged list of changes, together just six changes out of many edits, while there were seven changes if you chose each edit on its own. That means, the merged list took only the latest change if there was a double change. This avoids extra work if for example commenting of the changes is needed, or if you want to get a quick look at the changes that make the end document, not those changes that were somehow "balanced out" in the meantime.

1. How can I get a merged overview of the changes of more than one edit? You cannot mark more than one edit by holding shift, for example. Do Google Docs or its Add-ons have the feature to choose an older edit and show all of the merged changes that came after it, up to the youngest edit (or even better, up to a younger edit of choice)?
2. Said button shows that it is at least possible somehow to get the changes of all of the edits down to *your* last view. I could not find a way to get that button just from the menu. Therefore: how to get that button or feature to see at least any merged changes after my last view, and not just at first opening when changes have been made by others?

You can only click on the version history link, but not on that nice button.

[image]